# Display number of items per category with .count rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count

I'm trying to display the number of photos a category has in a list.

For it, I'm trying to do in my view:

```
<%= @photos.zone.name("Zone1").count%>
<%= @photos.zone.name("Zone2").count%>
<%= @photos.zone.name("Zone3").count%>
<%= @photos.zone.name("Zone4").count%>
```

But this doesn't work, and I don't know if this will make a million requests to my ddbb.

Which is the correct way to do this? Making a scope for each category?

**Update**

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  # validate :validate_minimum_image_size
  has_many :tags , dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :zone
  validates_presence_of :title, :description, :category, :zone
  acts_as_votable
  is_impressionable
  before_destroy { |record| record.tags.destroy_all if record.tags.any? }

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  has_many :photos
  has_many :tags, through: :photos
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the models with their associations?

Comment: Is `@photos` a single instance or a collection?

Comment: @TamerShlash Photos is a nested resource of User. Photos are collections of all the photos within a category

Answer (score 0):

This line here is wrong because you are calling it on a collection, and it doesn't represent your data model correctly.

```
<%= @photos.zone.name("Zone1").count%>
```

Let's say you wanted to get the zone of each photo, you would do something like this:

```
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
  <%= photo.zone.count %>
<% end %>
```

This still does not make sense because your association states that **a photo belongs to a zone**. So a photo can only have one zone per your data model.

```
  class Photo
    # ...
    belongs_to :zone
  end
```

Based on this information, I will assume that you want to display zones, and the number of photos per zone. In which case you would do something like this:

```
<%= @zone.photos.count %>
```

Or, if you wanted to show multiple zones on the same page:

```
<% @zones.each do |zone| %>
  <%= zone.photos.count %>
<% end %>
```

How would you prepare the data? In your controller you would do something like this:

```
@zone = Zone.includes(:photos).find(params[:id]) # assuming a /zones/:id path
```

Or for multiple zones:

```
@zones = Zone.all.includes(:photos) # assuming a /zones/ path
```

It is also possible that you want to display photos grouped by zone, which is another story.

Comment: But how do I pass the Zone name or id? I want to have a list with:
zone - number of items of that zone. Thats why I need to have <%= @zone.photos.count %> with "Zone1", "Zone"...etc...otherwise, how do I know which zone to count?

Answer (score 0):

Extending **@Mohamad's answer**

The best bet is to use `counter_cache`.In your `Photo` model set `counter_cahe =>true` for zone

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  # validate :validate_minimum_image_size
  has_many :tags , dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :zone,:counter_cache => true #here
  validates_presence_of :title, :description, :category, :zone
  acts_as_votable
  is_impressionable
  before_destroy { |record| record.tags.destroy_all if record.tags.any? }

end
```

Then add a column `photo_counts` to your `zones` table and use it like this

```
<% @zones.each do |zone| %>

<%= zone.photo_counts %>

<%end%>
```

This avoids **`multiple requests`** to the **`DB`**.Look into this **[Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column)** for more info.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

simply
`<%= @photos.select{|photo| photo.zone.name == "Zone1"}.count%>`

Comment: try now. i mistakenly copy/pasted your bug :)